# Calculate $\int_{C(0,2)^+} \frac{z^3}{z^5 - 1} dz$

Tags: integration, analysis

How do I calculate this integral $\int_{C(0,2)^+} \frac{z^3}{z^5 - 1} dz$?

What I have done so far is the following:

set $z(t) = 2e^{it}$ with $t \in [0,2\pi]$ so we get.

$$
\int_{C(0,2)^+} \frac{z^3}{z^5 - 1} dz = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{(2e^{it})^3}{(2e^{it})^5 - 1}2ie^{it} dt = i\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{16e^{4it}}{32e^{5it} - 1}dt.
$$

Now setting $u(t) = 32e^{5it} + 1$ we get $du = 160ie^{5it}dt$.

How should I continue?

Comment: Do you know residue theorem?

Comment: I should know it and I've seen it. But I do not really understand it yet.

Comment: I do not know exactly what techniques they want you to use .

Comment: How would you use the residue theorem in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the denominator as
$$ 32e^{5it} \left( 1 - \frac{e^{-5it}}{32} \right). $$
The latter bracket can then be expanded in a convergent power series to give the integrand as
$$ \frac{e^{-it}}{2} \left( 1 + \frac{e^{-5it}}{32}+\left(\frac{e^{-5it}}{32} \right)^2 + \dotsb \right). $$
It is easy to check that this is uniformly convergent on the interval of integration, so you can interchange the sum and the integral, and use the formula
$$ \int_0^{2\pi} e^{nit} \, dt = \begin{cases} 0 & n \neq 0 \\ 2\pi & n=0 \end{cases} $$
to find that the integral is zero.